# How do I create measures that are not aggregated data?

Tags: cube.js

I have a simple table which has a number(say sales) as one column which describes the sales done for a product. I also have ~25 products.

Now, I want to import this sales as a measure into cube. However, i am not sure what it's type and sql parameters should be. Setting the type to 'number' and sql to 'sales' gives error such as column "plan.sales" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add the sales column as a dimension, then you can define the aggregated measures like average sales or total of sales using the number of sales dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Сould you please share the env vars, the cube.js file, and the data schema?
I also recommend you follow up through [this guide](https://cube.dev/blog/cubejs-open-source-dashboard-framework-ultimate-guide/). I think it might help.